# Не получается объявить массив структур, которые описаны в другом классе

Tags: xcode, swift

У меня есть класс (допустим он называется ServerAPI), в котором есть метод, принимающий в качестве аргумента массив структур. Данная структура (допустим она называется Picfiles) описана в этом классе.

Затем из другого класса я объявляю экземпляр этого класса (ServerAPI) и хочу вложить массив, состоящий из структур, которые описаны классе ServerAPI. Но у меня не получается объявить и проинициализировать такой массив.

Если я пишу так: var pics = ServerAPI.Picfiles то xcode ругается и говорит, что надо удалить (), но без скобок это тоже не работает.

Как мне создать такой массив, чтобы вложить его в качестве аргумента в метод?

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается всё было очень просто. Надо было так написать

var pics : [ServerAPI.Picfiles] = []